# Auto populate field based on another field in Esri Collector

Tags: arcpy, arccatalog, arcgis-collector, state-plane

I'm looking to have an automatic conversion worked into an extra couple fields that will convert the latitude and longitude taken when collecting a point. Currently trying to convert the latitude and longitude to state plane coordinates. I've downloaded a toolbox that creates the latitude and longitude automatically from my Trimble gps receiver.

Answer (score 1):

The Collector cannot do "on the fly" calculations. That is perform analysis on a field based on user input in the App. You have two potential options here:

1) You publish the map in the projection system you want the fields to be populated with. The App will then capture these points in the coordinate system you want.

2) You publish the map as is, just adding in the fields you want the coordinates added to. Have a script which runs at a given time to pull in the information off the Server, run the process of populating the field with the coordinates and then republish the data back to the server with these coordinates in the attribute table.

When the user re-syncs the App, the points will have the converted coordinates in the attribute table.